# if user input match key in dict then print the value

Tags: python

```
test = input() <- you type 1

Test = {
        "1": "Test1",
        "2": "Test2",
        "3": "Test3",
        "4": "Test4",
        "5": "Test5"
    }
```

now i want to print the value "Test1"

Comment: What's the problem? This is the most basic operation with dictionaries.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: you should find some tutorial or video tutorial. Or at least something like [Learn X in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python/) `Where X=Python`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
test = input()
if test in Test:
    print(Test[test])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = input()

Test = {
    "1": "Test1",
    "2": "Test2",
    "3": "Test3",
    "4": "Test4",
    "5": "Test5"
    }
try:
    print(Test[test])
except KeyError:
    print('Not found')
```